# how to retrieve dynamic field info configured in lightning record pages

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, dynamic

We are working on clone functionality and would like to have same fields on clone button what configured on lightning record page.The standard clone does have field layout accoridng to page layout.

I am trying to build the lwc with record form and it also has the same layout from page layout.

Is there a way i can get what all fields have been used in dynamic field on lightning record pages?